# How to structure a JMeter test plan properly for a sockets.io scenario - event "subscription"

Tags: sockets, websocket, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

#### Scenario Outline

Test sends a REST API request to activate a game.
Website receives a socket.io event and displays an alert on the browser.

#### Question

Since I don't know when the event will be sent, do I need to run a WebSocket Sampler, or perhaps a WebSocket Single-Read Sampler, in a loop, until I get the matching message?
So far in my attempts, I can connect to the event server and get message, but they are empty frames or messages are entirely different from the below.

I expect a message like this, which I am able to verify manually using the browser debugger.

```
{
    "locationId": 110,
    "name": "GAME_STARTED",           <---------------------
    "payload": {
        "id": 146418,
        "boxId": 2002,
        "userId": 419,
        "createdAt": "2022-02-17T09:10:16",
        "lastModifiedAt": "2022-02-17T09:10:22.189",
        "completedAt": "2022-02-17T09:10:22.07",
        "activationMethod": "TAG",
        "nfcTagId": "123423423412342134",
        "gameCount": 1,
        "app": false
    }
}﻿
```

Alternatively, would this work?

```
thread A:
open socket
while (true):
   read socket
   if message ~ 'GAME_STARTED':
       break

thread B:
send HTTP REST API request   # triggers event to be sent
```

Here are the parameters used to connect and where I specify the response pattern, which needs wildcards or a JSON expression.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider using **WebSocket Text Frame Filter**

[image]

If you add the filter configured like above it will remove all the frames which don't contain `GAME_STARTED` text so the WebSocket Single Read sampler will not "see" them, this way you can just have one sampler without any loops or other logic.

More information:

- [Smart close with filter sample](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/samples/Smart%20close%20with%20filter%20sample.jmx) example test plan
- [JMeter WebSocket Samplers - A Practical Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers-a-practical-guide)